# PHP - Editing JSON data in Facebook Graph api

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

When i call fb graph api [using php sdk] it shows results in something like this :-

```
{"from":
     {
      "name":"xxxx",
      "id":"xxxx"
     },

 "created_time": 
      {
       "date":"2019-03-13 14:34:48.000000",
       "timezone_type":1,
       "timezone":"+00:00"
       },

  "message":".............",
  "id":"xxxxx"
}
```

where **created_time** divided into 3 parts. is there any way to make it like this?

```
 "created_time":"2019-03-13 14:34:48.000000"
```

exactly like fb graph api -

```
 {
      "from": {
        "name": "xxxx",
        "id": "xxxx"
      },
      "created_time": "2019-03-13T14:34:48+0000",
      "message": "xxxx",
      "id": "xxxx"
    }

that would easy for me to upload data in localhost :) 
Thank You.
```

Comment: you would have to do that on your own, afaik there is no way to tell facebook to get different formats.

Comment: Can you please show that part of your code that processes this response?

Comment: you could just debug the code to find out if the api call is different, btw

Comment: The first one is not the original JSON data received from the API, the PHP SDK has already parsed the created time into a DateTime instance here.

Comment: @Luschn ,, now idk know how can i upload only <b>date </b> to localhost :( same output for array too.

Comment: What are you even talking about, “upload in localhost” … You already have that data on the server side, that’s where PHP runs. So what exactly do you want now? Please give a _proper_ explanation of what problem you are actually trying to solve here.

Comment: @04FS, when i call "fb-callback.php " it gives me a straight line json data.

Comment: Well then it would probably make most sense to use the `getBody` or `getDecodedBody` methods of `Facebook\FacebookResponse`.

Comment: @04FS, i want to upload NAME , comment time & message in a table in **mysql server** [localhost/phpmadmin]....  i've created a web page where i can show those data and analyze  them.

Comment: @frzsombor , php code:- `
try {
  // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/<post-id>/comments/?fields=from,created_time,message&limit=100',
    $accessToken
  );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
echo "<pre>";
echo $graphEdge; `

Comment: @frzsombor  Full code : https://pastebin.com/BxYdm2e4